# PostPersist in Doctrine Slim v3

Tags: doctrine-orm

I use doctrine with Slim V3, I want to have PostPersist / PostUpdate function

this is my entity

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="xxxx", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="xxxx", columns={"xxxx"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 */
class MyEntity
{

....

/**
 * Set lastUpdate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $lastUpdate
 *
 *
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function setLastUpdate($lastUpdate)
{
    $this->last_update = new \DateTime('now');


    return $this;
}
```

But When I persist the entity, my field remains Null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the database value, you are listening for the wrong event. Regarding to the [doc](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#lifecycle-events):

> - postPersist - The postPersist event occurs for an entity after the entity has been made persistent. It will be invoked after the database
>     insert operations. Generated primary key values are available in the
>     postPersist event.
> - postUpdate - The postUpdate event occurs after the database update operations to entity data. It is not called for a DQL UPDATE
>     statement.

So better you handle the `pre` event instead of the `post` event. As example:

```
/**
 *
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function setLastUpdate()
{
    $this->last_update = new \DateTime('now');


    return $this;
}
```

Hope this help